# How can I make my multiplication-table aligned?

Tags: ruby, command-prompt, text-alignment

Im making a program where you give 2 inputs, the amount of columns and amount of rows to a multiplikation-system. But when having bigger numbers (2 digit numbers) it makes the system unaligned.

Theres nothing wrong with the code. All I want is something that makes the "|" aligned vertically.

I want the output to be;

```
| 3 | 6  | 9  |
| 4 | 8  | 12 |
| 6 | 12 | 18 |
```

But I get the output;

```
| 3 | 6 | 9 |
| 4 | 8 | 12 |
| 6 | 12 | 18 |
```

Comment: Please show us the code for your latest attempt and where you got stuck.

Comment: You need to edit to define the array of elements you wish to display (e.g, "Given the array `arr = [3, 6, 9, 4, 8, 12, 6, 12, 18]` I wish to...").

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = [3, 6, 9, 4, 8, 12, 6, 12, 18]
nrows = 3

width = arr.minmax.map { |n| n.to_s.size }.max
  #=> 2

puts arr.each_slice(nrows).map { |row| '| ' +
  row.map { |n| "%-#{width}d" % n }.join(' | ') + ' |' }
| 3  | 6  | 9  |
| 4  | 8  | 12 |
| 6  | 12 | 18 |
```

Perhaps you'd prefer to right-adjust:

```
puts arr.each_slice(nrows).map { |row| '| ' +
  row.map { |n| "%#{width}d" % n }.join(' | ') + ' |' }
|  3 |  6 |  9 |
|  4 |  8 | 12 |
|  6 | 12 | 18 |
```

See [Kernel#sprintf](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) for formatting directives. If it is known that all elements of `arr` are non-negative we could write:

```
width = arr.max.to_s.size
  #=> 2
```

If you wish to make each column as narrow as possible, adjusting right, you could do the following.

```
arr = [3, 6, 9, 4, -81, 12, 6, 12, 1800]
nrows = 3
```

```
col_widths = nrows.times.map { |i|
  (i..nrows*nrows-1).step(3).map { |j| arr[j].to_s.size }.max }
  #=> [1, 3, 4]

puts arr.each_slice(nrows).map { |row| '| ' +
  row.map.with_index { |n,i| "%#{col_widths[i]}d" % n }.join(' | ') + ' |' }
| 3 |   6 |    9 |
| 4 | -81 |   12 |
| 6 |  12 | 1800 |
```

Comment: Not `'%-2d' % n`?

Comment: Or you could use String#ljust / String#rjust.

Comment: @Sergio, that's what I started with. Changed it to please tadman.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: ah, I see. TIL then. :)